# Apollo error handling with react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, apollo, apollo-client

Have problem with apollo error handling.

Basically i need global error handling. Right now actually i have global error handling but it always shows me react-natiev red box.

Is there a way to change it to my own screen view? (`<ErrorComponent/>`) Or something? Instead of red box?

Thanks!

Version of apollo 1.9.2

## Here is my global error handler:

```
const handleErrors = ({ response }, next) => {
  const res = response.clone()
  if (!res.ok) {
    if (res.status === 500) {
      throw new Error('Error')
    }
    return next();
  }
}

networkInterface.useAfter([{
  applyAfterware: handleErrors,
}]);

const client = new ApolloClient({
  networkInterface,
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem and resolve the error handler globally mention in `apollo-link-error` package.

reference url: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/error-handling/

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {AsyncStorage, Alert} from 'react-native';
import {ApolloClient} from 'apollo-client';
import {InMemoryCache} from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import {HttpLink} from 'apollo-link-http';
import {setContext} from 'apollo-link-context';
import { onError } from "apollo-link-error";

const httpLink = new HttpLink({uri: NetworkInterFace});

const errorLink = onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError }) => {
  if (graphQLErrors)
    graphQLErrors.map(({ message, locations, path }) =>
      console.log(
        `[GraphQL error]: Message: ${message}, Location: ${locations}, Path: ${path}`,
      ),
    );

  if (networkError) {
    console.log(`[Network error]: ${networkError}`);
  }
});

const authLink = setContext(async (req, {headers}) => {
  let userDetails = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');
  userDetails = JSON.parse(userDetails);
  if (userDetails === null) {
    return {
      ...headers,
      headers: {
        authorization: '',
      },
    };
  } else {

    return {
      ...headers,
      headers: {
        authorization: userDetails.token,
      },
    };
  }
});
const link = errorLink.concat(authLink.concat(httpLink));
export const client = new ApolloClient({
  link,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});
```